# Hyper terminal equivalent in windows 8

Tags: microcontroller, communication, windows

I need to do some communication between 8051 micro-controller and PC . There used to be a hyper terminal for this purpose in windows XP. I m using windows 8 now. So can anyone suggest me some equivalent of hyper terminal in windows 8  for the purpose of serial comm. between micro-controller and PC.

Comment: You may use Tera Term.

Comment: Hyperterminal is usually considered horrible for a variety of reasons. Putty, RealTerm, TeraTerm and a few others are commonly used.

Comment: Also see docklight

Comment: For future reference, this may have been a better question for the SuperUser SE site.

Answer (score 33):

[PuTTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY), surprisingly enough, can act as a full-featured serial terminal. It supports full-blown VT-102/VT-80 command codes too.
[image]

[There is Termite](http://www.compuphase.com/software_termite.htm), which is a very nice, no-installation 200K exe:
[image]

Parallax also has a [nice serial terminal](http://www.parallax.com/PropellerDownloads/tabid/832/Default.aspx).
[image]

Comment: +1 for PuTTY; one of the best damn little utilities to ever grace the blackened soul of a machine running Windows.

Comment: PuTTY is a wonderful free program, and source is available too. +1 and kudos.

Comment: +1 for PuTTY. A must-have.

Comment: While PuTTY *is* nice, I far prefer cygwin for my ssh duties. On the other hand, it is a lot less compact.

Comment: Having cygwin for ssh connection only is like drying your hair with jet engine IMO. Also +1 to PuTTY.

Comment: @zzz - But it gets your hair REALLY dry, REALLY fast ;) Anyways, I use the cygwin bash shell a lot too, so it's more that I had it already, then I installed it for just that purpose.

Answer (score 7):

RealTerm is also useful program..
[image]

Comment: Does RealTerm work on Windows8?

Comment: RealTerm 2.0.0.70 seems to work on Windows 8 (x64).  Initially I had to run as administrator, but at some point something changed and now it works even if I don't run as administrator.

Answer (score 7):

[HTerm is a gem!](http://www.der-hammer.info/terminal/)
I highly recommend you give it a try. While not being a pure terminal, it supports some nice features like (optional) concurrent display of Ascii, Hex, Dec and Bin. Its very straightforward to use and consists of a single exe file without any special dependencies.

I've used this on WinXP and Win7 without problems.

[Download (.zip file)](http://www.der-hammer.info/terminal/hterm.zip)

[image: HTerm UI]

[image: HTerm UI]

Answer (score 4):

I'll just add TeraTerm in and hTerm in case you're really going low-level, but mainly I use PuTTY.

Answer (score 4):

I use ScriptCommunicator. It has many features and a very useful script interface: http://sourceforge.net/projects/scriptcommunicator/

main window:
[image: main window]

example script GUI:
[image: example script GUI]

Answer (score 1):

I like [Terminal](https://sites.google.com/site/terminalbpp/).  It has a very easy to use interface, macro capability, and quick graphing tools.

Answer (score 0):

I generally use RealTerm.  However I have had problems sometimes with it locking up in Windows 7, particularly with virtual COM ports like USB.

So I got a copy of [HyperTerminal Private Edition](http://www.hilgraeve.com/hyperterminal/), by Hilgraeve Inc. which is the company that wrote the original HyperTerminal for Microsoft. They indicate it works with Windows 7, 8, and Vista.  As others have said, it isn't that great a terminal program but it was able to connect to a virtual COM port in Windows 7 on a development board  that RealTerm was unable to.

Comment: Save your money and use PuTTY, no problem so far with virtual serial ports with MikroE, Arduino etc.

Comment: I like PuTTY as well, it is my standard program for doing SSH.