# Which software should I use to send data to MCU (Atmega8)?

Tags: communication, atmega

I have made level converter circuit for RS232 to UART using MAX232. But I'm stuck, because I don't know how to send data to MCU. Googling the problem tells me to use hyperterminal but that is not available in Win 8. Please tell me how to do it? I'm using Atmega8 to communicate with PC.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electronic design.

Comment: An alternative for hyperterminal is [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)

Comment: @LeonHeller - no, software tools specifically needed for embedded hardware projects (of which a basic serial terminal would be an example, even though it once had other consumer uses) is *explicitly* on topic here.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/52659/16051). Btw, how do i reference a post as related to this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tera Term is an Open Source alternative to Windows Hyperterm.
http://ttssh2.sourceforge.jp/index.html.en

Not sure if it runs on Windows 8 though.

Comment: [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) is another alternative. It is also open source. The site doesn't highlight it's support of serial in addition to ssh & telnet, but it does support it.

Comment: @Psychic i checked this link and "requirements" tab inform me that this opensource can be used on win 8 also. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I ran it in Windows 8 just yesterday. It's pretty good for SSH too!

Answer (score 1):

We're big fans of [Terminal by Bray](https://sites.google.com/site/terminalbpp/), it has many useful features such as being able to display / send data as raw hex (rather than just printable ASCII) and automated challenge/response, plus useful macros.

PuTTY is good as a user interface to something running Linux or similar, but Bray's is better for raw serial comms (non-human readable).